# imagen gif como loader, sobrepuesto de manera traslúcida a contenido de elemento DIV con CSS

Tags: html5, css3, wordpress, gif, preloader

Tengo el siguiente código html que se muestra en una parte de las entradas de WordPress

```css
#descarga {
    position: relative;
}

.overlay{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8) url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdcUt.gif") center no-repeat;
}

fieldset.fieldbox {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 3px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.75);
    border-top: 4px solid #464646;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #464646;
    border-left: 4px solid #464646;
    border-right:  4px solid #464646;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

div.enlaces_box, .enlaces_box span, .enlaces_box a, .enlaces_box img, .enlaces_box b, .enlaces_box i, .enlaces_box ul, .enlaces_box li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

.enlaces_box {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px 0px -1px;
    background: rgb(38, 43, 54);
}

.enlaces_box ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.enlaces_box li, .enlaces_box ul {
    margin: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

.enlaces_box ul.enlaces li.elemento {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    color: rgb(140, 140, 156);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 13px;
}

.enlaces_box ul.enlaces li.headers {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 12px;
    background: rgb(30, 34, 43);
    padding: 10px 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.enlaces_box ul.enlaces li.elemento:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0px;
}

.enlaces_box ul.enlaces li.elemento span {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 2%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}


.enlaces_box ul.enlaces li.elemento span.a select {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-align-last: center;
}

.enlaces_box {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

.enlaces_box ul.enlaces li.elemento span.b i.fab  {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

#mensaje-fuentes {
    text-align: center;
}

#link-fuente {
    text-align: center;
}

.fas fa-caret-down::before {
    content: "\f0d7";
}

.enlaces_box a {
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out 0s;
    color: rgb(122, 136, 157);
}

.enlaces_box ul.enlaces li.elemento a {
    color: rgb(150, 157, 174);
}

.fas fa-download::before {
    content: "\f019";
}

.enlaces_box ul.enlaces li.elemento span b {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: rgb(89, 138, 245);
}

.enlaces_box ul.enlaces li.elemento .a img {
    width: 31px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

fieldset.fieldbox {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 3px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.75);
    border-top: 4px solid #464646;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #464646;
    border-left: 4px solid #464646;
    border-right:  4px solid #464646;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

div.datos-tecnicos-box, .datos-tecnicos-box span, .datos-tecnicos-box a, .datos-tecnicos-box img, .datos-tecnicos-box b, .datos-tecnicos-box i, .datos-tecnicos-box ul, .datos-tecnicos-box li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

.datos-tecnicos-box {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px 0px -1px;
    background: rgb(38, 43, 54);
}

.datos-tecnicos-box ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.datos-tecnicos-box li, .datos-tecnicos-box ul {
    margin: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

.datos-tecnicos-box ul.datos-tecnicos li.elemento {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    color: rgb(140, 140, 156);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 13px;
}

.datos-tecnicos-box ul.datos-tecnicos li.headers {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 12px;
    background: rgb(30, 34, 43);
    padding: 10px 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.datos-tecnicos-box ul.datos-tecnicos li.elemento:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0px;
}

.datos-tecnicos-box ul.datos-tecnicos li.elemento span {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 2%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.datos-tecnicos-box ul.datos-tecnicos li.elemento span.a {
    width: 20%;
}

.datos-tecnicos-box ul.datos-tecnicos li.elemento span.b {
    width: 26.5%;
}

.datos-tecnicos-box ul.datos-tecnicos li.elemento span.c {
    width: 14%;
}

.datos-tecnicos-box ul.datos-tecnicos li.elemento span.d {
    width: 20.5%;
}

.datos-tecnicos-box ul.datos-tecnicos li.elemento span.e {
    width: 19%;
}

.datos-tecnicos-box {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

.datos-tecnicos-box ul.datos-tecnicos li.elemento span.a i.fab {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}


.datos-tecnicos-box a {
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out 0s;
    color: rgb(122, 136, 157);
}

.datos-tecnicos-box ul.datos-tecnicos li.elemento a {
    color: rgb(150, 157, 174);
}

.fas fa-download::before {
    content: "\f019";
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="descarga" class="fieldbox">
<div class="loading overlay"></div>
    <div class="enlaces_box">
        <ul class="enlaces">
            <li class="elemento headers">
                <span class="a">SERVIDOR <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></span><span class="b">SO <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></span><span class="c">FORMATO <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></span>
            </li>
            <li id="li1" class="elemento">
                <span class="a"><select id="iv1" class="select_host"><option value ="">Elija Servidor</option><option value="ClickNUpload.co">ClickNUpload.co</option></select></span><span class="b"><i class="fab fa-windows"></i> 32 Bits</span><span class="c">Instalable</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Lo que deseo es que se sobreponga el loader, cuando yo aplique el código CSS con las reglas que lo ubican centrado, encima del DIV con la clase "enlaces_box" (con Javascript yo lo agrego o lo retiro a mi gusto, ya que el loader no va a aparecer siempre). Como pueden ver actualmente me vi obligado a usar un DIV con las clases "loading" y "overlay", quiero prescindir de él para tener el código "mas limpio", en su lugar reutilizar el DIV "enlaces_box" que ya tengo (además quiero que el loader se centre en el contenido de este DIV), además el efecto de opacidad y la imagen "centrada" se aplique solamente al DIV con la clase "overlay" (no a todo el body de la página como se observa en el Snippet).

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucioné. Lo de eliminar el DIV, veo que no se va a poder, pero no es tan importante.

Solo, agregué este estilo al Fieldset:

Agregué

```css
#descarga {
    position: relative;
}
```